# How to set changes view as default in Fork?

Tags: git, git-fork-client

When I click on a commit in Fork 1.0.88, there will be 3 tabs on the detail view, commit, changes, file tree:

[image: Fork Commit Changes File Tree]

By default, it's Commit, then I have to click on Changes. How can I make Changes default?

Comment: For anyone else who ends up here looking for an answer, currently this isn't available as a setting. The a workaround that I've found is using the keyboard shortcut to show the changes view which is `Ctrl` + `1` as per [this issue](https://github.com/ForkIssues/TrackerWin/issues/333).